# I am getting { } on the end of my output. What is causing this and how do I remove it?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying my hand at a simple gui that encrypts and decrypts messages with a "secret number"/key identifier in the same window for fun. So far it works and I am pretty happy with it. My only issue is I am getting the output return in my crypt() function of what I want followed by {}. Using the normal print() function, I do not have that issue. However, using the GUI it does. I imagine it is the package tkinter doing this?

My code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox


def crypt():
    so = int(nu1.get())
    inp = str(nu2.get().upper())
    old_dic = {chr(i): i * (int(so)+int(so))for i in range(ord("A"), ord("A") + 26)}   
    if len(inp) >= 1:
        bit = list(inp)
        spell = list(map(old_dic.get, bit))
        spell = spell[::-1]            
        ans1 = (*spell, "")
        blank4.insert(0, ans1)
        
    else:
        print("Improper input.")
        
main = Tk()
Label(main, text = "Enter secret number:").grid(row=0)
Label(main, text = "Cryptify:").grid(row=1)
Label(main, text = "Encrypted output:").grid(row=2)

Button(main, text='Show', command=crypt).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

nu1 = Entry(main)
nu2 = Entry(main)
blank4 = Entry(main)
                   
nu1.grid(row=0, column=1)
nu2.grid(row=1, column=1)
blank4.grid(row=2, column=1)



mainloop()
```

Output for the Encryption I am getting looks like this:

> Secret Number: 45

> Cryptify: Hello

> Encrypted Output:  7110 6840 6840 6210 6480 {}

Output should look like this:

> Secret Number: 45

> Cryptify: Hello

> Encrypted Output:  7110 6840 6840 6210 6480

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mre].

Comment: It means you are passing a list or tuple to a tkinter function when it expects a string.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I am not sure what part to reduce as it is already pretty small code and I included all aspects that may be causing the issue. Also in the bottom I include my inputs and outputs so it can be replicated. What else should I be doing?

Comment: A good way is to start from scratch an add the least amount of code required to create the same problem. For example, instead of multiple Entrys and Labels, a single one should be sufficient.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I didn't know enough about this package to understand where my problem is. So I included a good chunk of it. I will update it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is quite simple, `tkinter` uses `tcl` and it does not know what python `list` or `tuple` are, and it is `tcl` way of reading tuples/lists by putting it inside `{}` like you noticed, so **convert it to a string**, like:

```
ans1 = (*map(str,spell), "")
blank4.insert(0, ' '.join(ans1))
```

Similarly do so for all the places where this is curly braces seen.

Comment: I tried this and now I get this error:
  
return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-563-dc178311fd14>", line 15, in crypt
    ans1 = ''.join((*spell, ""))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: The print output of what I have in my original code is: [7110, 6840, 6840, 6210, 6480]
with inputs at so = 45 and inp = hello.

Comment: Your updated code works! Thank you so much. This was driving me insane!

Comment: ans1 = (*map(str,spell), "")

# The empty string was to remove any punctuation that may have been put in.

Comment: @FannyPackFanatic Okay then you can use the first version. Or do whatever works, the idea is to give a string and not a tuple.