# how to prevent { } to show up when using space in a string in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a GUI with tkinter where I type in a string, and then after clicking on 'add' it shows up on the GUI in a list with the previous strings I added. When my string contains a space or enter, these {  } symbols show up around my string.
[the list in GUI with and without space in inserted string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whswT.png).

I have tried to remove them without succes. Where should I add code to remove them/ is there a way to prevent these showing up?

I boiled down the code as much as possible

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

main_window = tk.Tk()

string = tk.StringVar() 
list= StringVar()
list2= []

def add():
    list2.append(string.get())
    list.set(list2)
    return


Button(main_window,text="add", command= add).grid(row=1, column=1)
Label(main_window, textvariable= list).grid(row=4, column=0)
Entry(main_window,textvariable= string, width=25, borderwidth=5).grid(row=0,column=1)


main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you trying to set a `StringVar` object's value to a list of strings? Try `list.set("|".join(list2))` instead of `list.set(list2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. #Also don't use variables as `[list,tuple,dict,str,int]` etc.

```
lst.set(' '.join(list2))
```

Instead of plain

```
lst.set(list2)
```

Comment: Isn't this what I said in the comments?

Comment: Didn't see that. If you don't like someone taking your comment and putting it as an answer... that's your problem buddy. An answer is an answer. A comment is an answer. Why the `|` when joining. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: Just saying that you didn't see it is good enough for me given that the difference was only a few minutes.

Comment: Look at the rest of my comment please.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304126/is-it-correct-to-answer-copying-from-comments-by-other-users

Comment: I know what comments are. Also I used a `|` to make it more obvious once OP tries it out

Comment: Also, look at your comment now. The user has gotten an answer. Where do they accept that? They can't. Look at the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), it shows when to comment and when to not.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/67462874/13382000

Comment: @BuddyBob Don't want to argue right now but isn't the point of this website to answer people's questions? If the question is answered, it should be fine.

Comment: Yes that correct. But, if we provide an answer, future user's can have an easy place to look when they have this similar question.

Comment: @BuddyBob Given the simplicity of the problem, I thought that it was a duplicate but it would have been much faster for me to write a comment. If someone else googles this problem, they are most likely going to find the older question and not this one anyways