# Update gg["text"] by using strings and other variable in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Assume `points = 78` and I want to do similar things like this:

```
gg["text"] = f"No more moves, GAME OVER. Here's the final score: {points["text"]}"
```

it showed **error** on pointing `"text"`, so i changed to the acceptable code:

```
gg["text"] = "No more moves, GAME OVER. Here's the final score", points["text"]
```

but it showed "{No more moves....} 78" in the label

How can I make "**78**" into the curly braces?

**Edit**: The problem is solved, the answer to this question is under comment

Comment: try `{{points["text"]}}` instead of `{points["text"]}`

Comment: ```Syntaxerror: invalid syntax```

Comment: then how do u want it to show when you try `print(gg['text'])` ?

Comment: try `gg["text"] = f"{{No more moves, GAME OVER. Here's the final score: {points["text"]}}}"`

Comment: same error, the error is pointing ```"text"```

Comment: sry try `gg["text"] = f"{{No more moves, GAME OVER. Here's the final score: {points['text']}}}"`

Comment: It work! Thanks!!!!!
Actually, I just realised ```'text'``` is enough to remove the curly bracket

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am getting { } on the end of my output. What is causing this and how do I remove it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67462874/i-am-getting-on-the-end-of-my-output-what-is-causing-this-and-how-do-i-remo)

Comment: This `gg["text"] = f"No more moves, GAME OVER. Here's the final score: {points['text']}"` should solve the `{}` from appearing

Comment: To be precise, the similar question solution doesn't answer my current situation. The curly bracket is outside of the sentence but my problem is the curly bracket is not fully covered "78"/eliminating curly bracket.

(To reply your second comment: (Yeah, cool cloud. I figured it that))