# How to remove curly braces from a text widget

Tags: tkinter, strip

I would like to list the list of frame.conifg in the Text Widget. The characters "{}" should be removed from the text. Can someone explain to me, why that will not removed with the following code?

```
liste  = frame_01.config()

for item in liste:
       texteditor.insert(tk.INSERT, (item.strip("{}"), ":", liste[item], "\n"))
```

This is how the list looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oheaE.png)

With this code I get the following error message:
*texteditor.insert(tk.INSERT, (item.translate(str.maketrans('', '', '{}')), ":", self.mainwindow.liste[item], "\n"))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str*

```
for item in liste:
           texteditor.insert(tk.INSERT, (item.translate(str.maketrans('', '', '{}')), ":", liste[item], "\n"))
```

Comment: This would only work if the characters "{}" are at the end or start of the string. Is this the  case?

Comment: No, the characters are disordered

Comment: This is an xy problem. What are you actually trying to accomplish? The curly braces are there because you're converting a dictionary of lists to strings. There are almost certainly better ways to accomplish what you need without converting the dictionary to a list, the list to a string, then remove the curly braces. If you can show an example of what you want the output to look like, we can show you the best way to get it.

Comment: I did not quite understand that, because unfortunately my English is not very good. Can you rewrite my code accordingly?

Comment: I don't know what output you expect, so I don't know how to rewrite the code. Please [edit] your question to include what sort of output you're expecting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am getting { } on the end of my output. What is causing this and how do I remove it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67462874/i-am-getting-on-the-end-of-my-output-what-is-causing-this-and-how-do-i-remo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curly braces aren't in the data, they are only added by tkinter because you are passing a list to a function that expects a string. Tcl (the embedded language that tkinter uses) encodes lists differently than python, by adding curly braces around list elements that have spaces or tabs.

The solution is to explicitly format the data rather than trying to let Tcl format the data. One way is to do it something like this:

```
for item in liste:

    # convert the list of values to a list of strings
    values = [str(x) for x in liste[item]]

    # explicitly join the list of strings to create a single string
    str_values = " ".join(values)

    # insert the string into the text widget
    textedit.insert("end", f"{item}: {str_values}\n")
```

Comment: values = [str(x) for x in liste[item]]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @sc19: this code works for me exactly as written. Regardless, the concept is the important thing to get out of this answer. You need to explicitly convert lists and dictionaries to strings before passing them to tkinter functions that expect strings.

Comment: It works now. I do not know why it did not work before. Many thanks for the help!