# Remove curly brackets in tkinter list box

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

Hi I am trying to remove the curly brackets in the `tkinter listbox`, however I need to maintain it as a tuple so when I use `curselection` I can populate the `entry` boxes.
Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import *

import sqlite3

def connect():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("Section_25_GUI_and_Postgres/books2.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title text, author text, year integer, isbn integer)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    
def insert(title, author, year, isbn):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("Section_25_GUI_and_Postgres/books2.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO book VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (title, author, year, isbn))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def view():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("Section_25_GUI_and_Postgres/books2.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM book")
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows 

# connect()
# insert("My Book 2", "Kevin Medri", 2020, 269494945)

def get_selected_row(event):
    
    try:
        global selected_tuple
        index = li1.curselection()[0]
        selected_tuple = li1.get(index)
        print(selected_tuple)
        e1.delete(0, END)
        e1.insert(END, selected_tuple[1])
        e2.delete(0, END)
        e2.insert(END, selected_tuple[2])
        e3.delete(0, END)
        e3.insert(END, selected_tuple[3])
        e4.delete(0, END)
        e4.insert(END, selected_tuple[4])
    except IndexError:
        pass

def view_command():
    li1.delete(0, END)
    for row in view():
        li1.insert(END, row)
        
def close_command():
        window.destroy()

window = tk.Tk()

window.title('Book Case')
window.geometry('-50+50')
window.resizable(False, False)
window.attributes('-alpha',0.9)
window.configure(background='#d7e1ff')

# UI options
paddings = {'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}
entry_font = {'font': ('Arial', 10)}

# configure style globally for labels and buttons
window.style = Style(window)
window.style.configure('TLabel', anchor='e', background='#d7e1ff', font=('Arial', 10))
window.style.configure('TButton', anchor='w', background='#d7e1ff', font=('Arial', 10))

l1 = Label(window, text='Title', **entry_font)
l1.grid(row=0, column=0, **paddings)

l2 = Label(window, text='Author', **entry_font)
l2.grid(row=0, column=2, **paddings)

l3 = Label(window, text='Year', **entry_font)
l3.grid(row=1, column=0, **paddings)

l3 = Label(window, text='ISBN', **entry_font)
l3.grid(row=1, column=2, **paddings)

title_text = StringVar()
e1 = Entry(window, textvariable=title_text, **entry_font)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1, **paddings)

author_text = StringVar()
e2 = Entry(window, textvariable=author_text, **entry_font)
e2.grid(row=0, column=3, **paddings)

year_text = StringVar()
e3 = Entry(window, textvariable=year_text, **entry_font)
e3.grid(row=1, column=1, **paddings)

isbn_text = StringVar()
e4 = Entry(window, textvariable=isbn_text, **entry_font)
e4.grid(row=1, column=3, **paddings)


li1 = Listbox(window, height=13, width=35, **entry_font)
li1.grid(row=2, column=0, rowspan=6, columnspan=2, **paddings)

sb1 = ttk.Scrollbar(window, orient='vertical', command=li1.yview)
sb1.grid(row=2, column=2, rowspan=6, sticky=tk.NS, **paddings)

li1.configure(yscrollcommand=sb1.set)
sb1.configure(command=li1.yview)

li1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', get_selected_row)

b1 = ttk.Button(window, text='View All', command=view_command)
b1.grid(row=2, column=3, **paddings)

b6 = ttk.Button(window, text='Close', command=close_command)
b6.grid(row=7, column=3, **paddings)

window.mainloop()
```

Here is result of my code when I click on View All

[On View All](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghg4P.jpg)

I need the entry boxes to fill when I click on one of the items in the list box but with no curly brackets in the listbox

[On click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNAdq.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am getting { } on the end of my output. What is causing this and how do I remove it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67462874/i-am-getting-on-the-end-of-my-output-what-is-causing-this-and-how-do-i-remo)

Comment: No that answer converts the origanal list elements to all strings and then joins them into one string. Yes it removes the brackets but breaks the ability to fill the entry boxes. I think it is the white space in the strings in the list that give the problem, just can't find a solution. Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: You can join the elements using comma, then you can get those elements later by splitting the string by comma.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] that doesn't depend on a database, by using some hard-coded data that looks exactly like the result of the query. Also, it looks like there's a lot of code in your example that isn't necessary to reproduce this problem that can be removed.

Comment: This is a clear duplicate of the question I just marked. You have to use `join` to make all the element of a iterable onto a string together and then put it into the listbox. So something like `li1.insert(END, ' '.join(map(str,row)))` will work. Extra `map` because the first item is an `int` and `join` require each item of the iterable to be a `str`.

Comment: @acw1668 I tried that however if there is a comma in the book name it breaks the string into too many list entries

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria if I use the solution you showed me it breaks the ability to fill the entry boxes when curselection() is used so in my case won't be a complete solution, unless there is a way to split the string back into its origanal list

Comment: Then use other separator, like `'|'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically the reason for `{}` appearing is already explained: [I am getting { } on the end of my output. What is causing this and how do I remove it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67462874/i-am-getting-on-the-end-of-my-output-what-is-causing-this-and-how-do-i-remo)

Now when you convert it to a string with `' '.join(map(str, row)))` you will notice, it is fine. But when you try to insert it into the entry boxes, you will face problem because it is no longer a `tuple`, it is a `str` and using `e1.insert(END, selected_tuple[1])` wont work the way you expect.

So you need a way to convert the string back to a tuple. So you could use something like `selected_tuple = selected_tuple.split(' ')`. But here you are splitting with every empty space. And there *can* be empty space between each item AND also inside the same item too, like `My Book Two`. So what you can do is, create two versions, one where each element is split using `' '` and other where it is split using `'-'` and create a link between them:

```
{ 'this is item one': 'this-is-item-one' }
```

Then your view function will be like:

```py
mapper = {}

def view_command():
    li1.delete(0, END)
    for row in view():
        items_hyphen = '-'.join(map(str, row)) # Hyphened
        items_space = ' '.join(map(str, row)) # Spaced
        
        li1.insert(END, items_space)
        
        mapper[items_space] = items_hyphen # Add to dictionary
```

And your get function will be like:

```
def get_selected_row(event):
    try:
        index = event.widget.curselection()
        selected_item_space = li1.get(index) # Get string from listbox
        selected_item_hyphen = mapper[selected_item_space] # Get corresponding hyphenated value from dictionary
        selected_list = selected_item_hyphen.split('-')[1:] # Slide to remove the ID

        ents = [e1, e2, e3, e4]
        for ent, value in zip(ents, selected_list): # Loop through `ents` and `selected_list` at the same time
            ent.delete(0, END) # Clear
            ent.insert(END, value) # Then insert

    except IndexError:
        pass
```

---

Alternatively, instead of using hyphened value, you could store the tuple itself as said by @acw1668:

```
def get_selected_row(event):
    try:
        ...
        selected_item_tuple = mapper[selected_item_space] # Get corresponding tuple from dictionary
        ...
        for ent,value in zip(ents, selected_item_tuple):
            ...

    except IndexError:
        pass

def view_command():
    li1.delete(0, END)
    for row in view():
        items_space = ' '.join(map(str, row)) # Spaced
        li1.insert(END, items_space)
        
        mapper[items_space] = row # Add to dictionary
```

Comment: Why don't you just save the tuple as the value of `mapper`, i.e. `mapper[items_space] = row`?

Comment: @acw1668 Ah yes, that seems like a good way too. I was driven by the idea of using a different separator initially.

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria I get the error: NameError: name 'mapper' is not defined

Comment: @kmedri Make an empty dictionary called `mapper` at the top: `mapper = {}`. Updated the code to reflect the change

Comment: Hi thank you so much for all your help @DelriusEuphoria, @acw1688, @Bryan Oakley. I just had to add some indexing to this line: `for ent,value in zip(ents, selected_tuple[1:]):` to fill in the entry boxes.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're trying to insert a tuple into a listbox, since each row is a tuple of the values from each individual column.

The listbox expects a string rather than a tuple, so it uses tcl's internal converter to convert the tuple to a string. For values in the tuple that have spaces or a few other special characters, tcl will place curly braces around the elements.

You should explicitly convert the tuple to a string before passing it to the listbox `insert` method so that this doesn't happen. One way to do that is to convert each row to a list by joining the list elements with a space (or any other character)

For example, the following example converts each row to a string by converting each column to a string, and then joining the columns together with a space.

```py
def view_command():
    li1.delete(0, END)
    for row in view():
        li1.insert(END, " ".join([str(column) for column in row]))
```

Comment: This seemed like a duplicate of the marked question, why not vote to close it?

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria: because the OP was having trouble understanding how the original applies in this instance. I decided this was the best way to help them.

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria yes that removes the curly brackets but how do I convert it back to its origanal tuple when curselection() is used to fill the entry boxes when a list box entry is clicked

Comment: @kmedri: if that's your goal, you either need to convert it to a form you can translate back to the original (for example, convert it to csv), or use the converted string as a key in a dictionary to get back the original data. The important thing to take away from this is that if you give tkinter a list or tuple when it expects a string, it will convert it to a string using its own internal rules. You need to be proactive and make sure you pass strings to tkinter that you control.

Comment: @BryanOakley If you don't mind, can I edit your answer to make it in a way the OP can use it to fill the entries too?

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria if you have a solution please add an answer, I would be really grateful